# Understanding Scala's Extractor - Pattern with Zero variable and Boolean Result

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Currently I am learning Scala Extractor and stuck in following confusion. I am unable to understand the following code. In the below pattern match, How UpperCase() return a String while the unapply method is designed to return Boolean?

```
  object UpperCase {
    def unapply(s: String): Boolean = s.toUpperCase == s
  }

  println(UpperCase.unapply("RAK")) //print boolean true or false.

  "RAK" match{
    case status @ UpperCase() => println("yes - "+ status) //How status holds RAK not boolean value?
    case _ => println("No")
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a [boolean extractor](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#extractor-patterns), that matches all values `v` for which `x.unapply(v)` yields `true`. The `@` is a [pattern binder](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-binders), which binds the variable `status` to the value matched by the pattern.

In your example, the pattern match the String "RAK", which is bound to the variable `status`.

Comment: That means, 'status' is actually holding the value that is matched by the pattern; which is 'RAK'. Thank you for your simplistic explanation.